# Is it completely valid to have a javascript function as key in an object?

Tags: javascript

Is it completely valid to have a javascript function as key in an object?

The following works, but I'm not sure it' s 100% (ecma or whatever body governs this) compliant

```
var f = function(){

};

var obj = {};

obj[f] = "a";


console.log(obj[f]);
```

Comment: I'm very curious to see a practical use-case for this.

Comment: I would say it is sort of pointless. the function is likely using toString to create a key of `["function() {...}"]`

Comment: keeping track / deregistering of anonymous subscriber-functions in a pub/sub-system. Not sure this is the right datastructure for the job though

Comment: @mplungjan: hmm you' re absolutely right, just tested it. So no it does not work.

Comment: could be useful for caching the result of some functions

Comment: @lc. See my comment on jAndy's answer. WeakMap works! To answer your hidden question: I'm going to use this in order to setup an auto-function-call-rate-limiting feature in my code. It's easiest to just pass the function and { map the last time the function was called **by** the function as the key } at the same time, instead of trying to use some kind of string number or enum.

Comment: @lc. Another use case would be for objects. Objects get converted into `"[object Object]"`, unless you use WeakMap. Having an object as a reference *by key* could be useful in some situations. (I can't really say the same about the usefulness of having an array by reference.) Also: classes. Think of classes the same as you would functions, in this context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is **zero** reason to do that, since *object keys* in ECMAscript may **only be** strings (for the time being, in ECMAscript 262 edition 3 and 5, by spec).

Things will change however in *ECMAscript 6*, where we will have *WeakMaps* and *object keys* also can be *objects* (I'm not sure about *function references*).

Even if a browser can distinguish object keys by *function reference* right now, its definitely questionable behavior, most likely experimental and should not be used right now.

Comment: Ooh interesting, didn't know this. It works! Just tried it. Note that you have to use `WeakMap.set(key, value)`, not `WeakMap[key] = value`. When I print out the former, it's storing the actual function, not a string of the function! Thanks.

Comment: Same goes for using `WeakMap[key]` for getting the value (don't, use `WeakMap.get(key)` instead). See my comments above as well.

Comment: Would you want to update your answer in 2021?

Comment: i dont agree with that so-called `zero reason`, we need dynamic keys sometimes

Answer (score 16):

It looks as it working, but it might not work as you expected.

The function is casted to string when used as a key:

```
var f = function(a) { return a; };
var obj = {};
obj[f] = 'abc';
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
//"{"function (a) { return a; }":"abc"}"
console.log(f.toString());
//"function (a) { return a; }"
var f2 = function (a) { return a; };
console.log(obj[f2]);
//"abc"
```

So, functions f and f2 are different objects, but they are the same when casted to string.

Comment: Though if `f` and `f2` behave the same since the underlying code is same then it is often not a problem.

Comment: It might be if they are closures. They might have the same source code, might be generated by the same outer function, but they would be bound to different values in the closures. So they would **behave** differently, but look the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = function(){

};
var obj = {};
obj[f] = "a";
console.log(obj['function (){\r\n\r\n}']);
```